# Is the function $f(x,y)=\begin {cases} ( x^3(i+1)-y^3(1-i))/(x^2+y^2) & x^2+y^2>0\\0 & x=y=0 \end{cases}$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, functions

Is the function $f(x,y)=\begin {cases} \frac{ x^3(i+1)-y^3(1-i)}{x^2+y^2} & x^2+y^2>0\\ 0 & x=y=0 \end{cases}$ continuous?

I would like to prove that thos function isn't continuous with help from two series and show that the limz doesn't equals the limf(z), z=(x,y)...sory for my English and my writting...I hope someone gets this (:

Comment: What topology do you have on your spaces? What are your spaces? Are you going from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Noramal topology, and yes the mepping is going so from R^2 to C.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb{R}^2$ with normal topology and range of $f$ is $\Bbb{C}$ with normal topology. Take $x=r\cos t$, $y=r\sin t$. Then if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ then
$$\frac{ x^3(i+1)-y^3(1-i)}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{r^3((1+i)\cos^3 t - (1-i)\sin^3t)}{r^2}$$

Since $|(1+i)\cos^3 t - (1-i)\sin^3t|\le 2\sqrt{2}$, we get $|f(x,y)|\le 2\sqrt{2}r=2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$. It forces $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y)=0=f(0,0)$ so $f$ is continuous at the origin. It is easy to check that $f$ is continuous at another points on $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I think that's corect so, but some people have shown that this function isn't continuous oO..and yes, assumtion is about the topology and etc is corect...

Comment: @banahova Can I see the proof of discontinuity of $f$ at the origin?

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't find it. This was my mini homework. I am not so good in english sorry I would better explain it in my own language.

Comment: could I look at your proof throught the definition of continuity? Can I set up the E=2^(1/2)ω because of the metrik |(x,y)|=r<ω that implicates |f(x,y)|<E than there exist a ω=E/(2^(1/2)) ??? Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: @banahova What is E? You want to say $\varepsilon$?

Comment: Yes I mean that epsilon (:

Comment: I think your argument has some problem. In your argument, $\omega\ge 0$ so $\varepsilon\ge 1$.